# Bind Core Data to UITextField to prevent boilerplate?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a form with about 10 `UITextField`. This form is used to create `NSManagedObject` with 10 fields. When user clicks "Done", I should do the following:

- Fill all fields in `NSManagedObject` with data from appropriate fields
- Run `validateForInsert:` and if some data is invalid, mark `UITextField` as invalid

I can do it manually, but it is a lot of boilerplate. I can use *KVC*, but I wonder if such framework exists already. Does there is any? How do you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You really do not want to use `validateForInsert` to generate UI-based validation feedback. The persistent store based validations are really only meant to ensure data integrity, not to provide a UI feedback mechanism. (Please also see Marcus Zarra's remark below.)

I would write all the validations for the attributes into the entity subclass. You could `tag` your text fields and keep the keys to your attributes in an appropriately ordered array (also produced by a convenience method in the entity subclass).

You could then identify the key via the text field tag:

```
if !Item.checkField(attributes[textField.tag]) {
    // alert the user of faulty input
}
```

You could of course also have one `isValid` method for the whole entity with appropriate error messages.

You could identify the fields for the appropriate attributes using the tag:

```
textField.text = Item.valueForKey(attributes[textField.tag])!
```

Comment: Better to create a text field subclass rather than repeatedly using tags

Comment: To be more accurate, the validation **is** meant for UI notification but it is meant for OS X UI notification, not iOS UI notification.  On OS X, the validation and notification is automatic, built into the Cocoa Bindings.  iOS does not have the same design and therefore the validation substructure of Core Data has very little value on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.